# Finding the current in a light bulb

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

I am doing this practice problem where it asks me to find the current through the light bulb at two different temperatures. The problem I am having is that I cannot find out how to do the problem with the higher temperature because I cannot find the resistivity needed. The information I am given is:

> For Filament:
>   Material: Tungesten
>   Length: 22.8 inches
>   Diameter: 0.046mm
>
> For Circuit:
>   Potential difference (voltage): 120V
>
> Temperatures to calculate current:
>   $T_1 = 20^\circ C$
>   $T_2 = 220^\circ C$

The problem that I am finding is that the resistivity is only given to me as:
Resistivity = $5.6\times10^{-8}$ at $20^\circ C$

But I also need to find the current at $220^\circ C$ which is why I am not sure how to do the second part of the problem because I don't have that information that I need to complete the second portion. All I am looking for help on is I feel like I am missing an equation to get the resistivity at higher temperatures. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe power is given at 2200 C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given the material (Tungsten) and the two temperatures required. A Google search using only the keywords "*resistivity temperature*" gave [Temperature Coefficient of Resistance](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-12/temperature-coefficient-resistance/) as the first result.

> $R = R_{ref}[1+\alpha(T-T_{ref})]$

Comment: My apologies, I saw that but I wasn't sure if thats what I needed, but thank-you for clarifying this for me.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question

Comment: @XcoderX apart from OP using *resistivity* instead of *resistance*, which part of "I am not sure how to do the second part of the problem ...  I feel like I am missing an equation to get the resistivity at higher temperatures." is not answered?